# Tab & independent dropdown button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create some tabs who represents different subobjects of an object

I need:

- Select the view of the object if the tab is clicked
- Add an independent dropdown button to edit or delete de subobject

but I don't know how to program that. This is my best aproach: http://jsfiddle.net/3u6pD/ wich is in the examples but this way I lost the selection of the tab on click

Can you help me to solve this issue in a TB way?

This the TB crowd plan to add such feature to the library?

Thanks a lot for the help